# How to config to show depended library jars rather than packages in "Packages view" of Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, intellij-idea

I installed Intellij IDEA 14 on my mac osx, but I found the display of depended library in Packages view was very annoying.The following is the screenshot of intellij idea, all the package name of depended jars are displayed here, they are indeed too many...

intellij idea screenshot:

[image]

**I just want to know how to config to make the library view look like eclipse, display all the depended jars rather than expanded package name.**

eclipse screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can; the package view is for viewing packages. I think the best you could do is turn off the "flatten" option. You can *remove* the "Libraries" content, but that's about it. Personally, it seems reasonable to me that the package view is organized by package. I almost never leave "Project" view anyway.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I switch to "Project" view and check "Flatten Packages" option, it looks better.

Answer (score 0):

You're in the package view. The package view, unsurprisingly, views packages.

Switching to the "Project" view looks like this:

[image]